# Users unable to access organisation Basemap Gallery in ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.2, arcgis-online, arcgis-online-basemaps

I have created a group (call it "Basemaps") in my organisation account in ArcGIS Online and published a number of maps with a single layer defined as a basemap.  These maps are all hosted on ArcGIS Server 10.2.1.  All of these maps are shared both with the organisation and the "Basemaps" group.

I have then added a number of users to the "Basemaps" group.

I have also edited the Organisation settings in ArcGIS online to use the basemap gallery from the "Basemaps" group rather than the standard ESRI basemaps.

When I go to create a new map and click on the basemaps gallery, I see a drop-down with all the basemaps I have created.  If I click on these I am able to use them.

When any other user who has been added to the "Basemaps" group does the same, they see the basemaps I have created, but when they click on it they get an error telling them that the basemap is unavailable.

Any ideas what I might have missed?
Is there a setting in ArcGIS online which I need to change?
Or is there something at the ArcGIS Server end which I need to change?

Comment: User role should be publisher?

Comment: The users trying to view the data are all publishers or admins to the organisation group.